# Are questions about book cover services on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I want to ask a question about book cover services but am unsure if it is on topic or not. I don't think this is defined in the help center, yet is still kind of related to writing/publishing. If questions about book cover services are off-topic here, can you recommend an SE Site where they might be accepted?

I did check out [this question](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1330/are-service-questions-on-topic), but it didn't quite give a definitive yes or no.

Comment: I think we've had questions on book cover services before. Certainly, we've had questions on book covers.